# Nested function in R

Tags: r, function, nested

Why the following nested function `f2` doesn't work as expected?

```
c = 2
f1 = function(a,b){
    (a+b)*c
}
f1(1,2) # 6

f2 = function(a,b,c){
    f1(a,b)
}
f2(1,2,c=3) # still 6, expect 9
```

**Update**

I found the following modification works:

```
f2 = function(a,b,c){
    c <<- c
    f1(a,b)
}
f2(1,2,c=3) # returns 9 as expected
```

But I am confused about the how a function call searches values along the path of environments. If my problem is just due to R's lazy evaluation, I just need `c <- c`. Then the new `c` will be in the environment where `f2` is called. Since `f1` is nested in `f2`, its environment is nested in that of `f2`. So when I need `c` in `f1`, it should be able to find `c` in the parent environment. However, it turns out that it can only find the global `c`, not the `c` in `f2`'s environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

R has lexical scope; a variable that is not assigned in a function is resolved against its static environment.  In your case, f1 sees the value of c in your global environment, which is 2.  Within f2, c == 3 because it is passed as an argument which masks the global c, but when f1 is called, it still sees c==2 from its enclosing environment.  You expected dynamic scoping, where c would take the value of its runtime environment (i.e., within f2). 
You can set c <- 3 outside the functions, before f2, or you can do this to copy the local value passed as 'c' in f2 to the global environment:

```
 f2 = function(a,b,c){
    c <<- c     # local argument c copied to global c
    f1(a,b)
 }
```

more discussion of lexical scope in R: https://darrenjw.wordpress.com/2011/11/23/lexical-scope-and-function-closures-in-r/

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I am looking for.